# unbounded value disappears at sorting

Tags: sorting, oracle-adf

I made a table with one of the columns being a date field. It's unbounded, but using a valuechangelistener and a bean to set the value to some rows in another table programatically. (this table shows the parent, the date is applied to its children). A checkbox in another column depends on this value, being disabled if the date field is empty, enabled when a date is filled in.

When a date is filled in, the bean applies this date to the other table rows and waits for a commit. If I don't commit however, but sort one of the columns, the filled in date disappears.

how could I keep the value in the table?